# Release Corona Game on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, coronasdk

I am using Corona Account Subscription as **Corona SDK Starter**. While building any app it makes me wait for sometime and ask to upgrade my account to built more powerful apps.

My question is: I am a beginner in Corona and just completed my simple 2D game.

> Do i need to purchase or upgrade my Corona account to build and release this app on google play.

I am new to Corona.

Please Help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to purchase any other version of corona to release on google play.
You can do it with the Corona SDK Starter version.

Comment: Hey Thankz for your reply...
If i need to monetize my application then i should buy the Basic License. Is that right??

Comment: Only if you need analytics modules (like Game analytics for example) or in-app purchases. If you would like to sell with a retail price you can still use the corona starter edition.